# Unable to use xpath as expected on document

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
  <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <Header>
    <MessageDetails>
      <Class>
      </Class>
      <Qualifier>request</Qualifier>
      <Function>submit</Function>
      <CorrelationID />
      <Transformation>
      </Transformation>
      <GatewayTest>0</GatewayTest>
    </MessageDetails>
    <SenderDetails>
      <IDAuthentication>
        <SenderID>
        </SenderID>
        <Authentication>
          <Method>clear</Method>
          <Role>principal</Role>
          <Value></Value>
        </Authentication>
      </IDAuthentication>
    </SenderDetails>
  </Header>
  <GovTalkDetails>
    <Keys>
      <Key Type="TaxOfficeNumber">
      </Key>
      <Key Type="TaxOfficeReference">
      </Key>
    </Keys>
    <TargetDetails>
      <Organisation>IR</Organisation>
    </TargetDetails>
    <ChannelRouting>
      <Channel>
        <URI>
        </URI>
        <Product></Product>
        <Version>
        </Version>
      </Channel>
      <timestamp>
      </timestamp>
    </ChannelRouting>
  </GovTalkDetails>
  <Body>
    <IRenvelope xmlns="">
      <IRheader>
        <Keys>
          <Key Type="TaxOfficeNumber">
          </Key>
          <Key Type="TaxOfficeReference">
          </Key>
        </Keys>
        <PeriodEnd>
        </PeriodEnd>
        <DefaultCurrency>GBP</DefaultCurrency>
        <IRmark>
        </IRmark>
        <Sender>Employer</Sender>
      </IRheader>
    </IRenvelope>
  </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

and I'm loading it into a `XMLDocument` using the `XMLDocument.load()`.

Now when I run xpath queries against it they are not responding as I would expect and I cant seem to find out why, I have used XPath Visualiser tool and it shows that for example //Keys/Key should return 4 nodes

When I run the following c#

```
document.SelectNodes(@"//Keys/Key") it returns 2 nodes not the expected 4.
```

Also when I run the following

```
document.SelectNodes(@"//Header") it returns 0 nodes
```

Also running

```
document.SelectNodes(@"GovTalkMessage") returns 0 nodes.
```

All suggestions and help greatfully received.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Your document is mixing up different namespaces.  Your queries uses no namespaces.

Comment: Looks like you're good assuming you fix the namespace issue.  Is your heart set on XPath?  Using XDocument to perform LINQ - to - XML queries I find much easier to use ( although not good to use if your XML document is very very big and needs to be buffered though)

Comment: @JNYRanger Hi, the reason for using XPath is just that I have used it quite a bit before but never with namespaces and hence this problem.  Can I if I use LINQ to XML easily modify the XML document, as this is just a basic template to which I will be adding a lot more data.  For those interested its a submission to the Revenue and Customs in the uk.

Comment: Absolutely!  LINQ to XML allows you to do everything you'd be able to do with XPATH plus lots more using functions.  Here's the MSDN page for you to get started:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx

Comment: By the way, if you are using namespaces with LINQ to XML you'll need to define an `XNamespace`, so just a heads up.  but once you do that and include it properly you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: @JNYRanger Cheers for that unfortunatley we are under the gun so I will have to stick to XPath for now, but as we're using LINQ elsewhere a definite need to refactor.

Comment: @BenWhyall Of course, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath needs namespaces. The tags you are trying to select are in one, so you have to tell the select where to look.

Comment: Hi, that has solved the problem that I was having as the document will have two namespaces is there anyway to select across both namespaces that is better than using local-name. ?

On a couple of the xpaths I may want all matching nodes regardless of namespace.

Comment: Not really a satisfying answer to this specific question. You should extend this comment, and actually _explain_ how to take namespaces into account. @BenWhyall If an element `a` should be matched regardless of its namespace, you have to use either `//*:a` or `//*[local-name() = 'a']`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thanks for this information I will be able to solve my issues